# How to search for the next word in a cell of a datagridview with a database? (VB.NET)(WindowsApplication)

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, windows

I have no idea how to do this, and thus I want to ask this question.
It's a windows form application, where I will search for the word in a datagridview, I've been searching High and Low for the reference and it seems like I'm out of options.

To be precise, I know the code, there's no error, everything's working but not like I expected.

First here is the Image:
[image: Query]

Then the code:

```
If query.Text <> "" Then
        adapter = New OleDbDataAdapter("select * from JobOrders where CLIENT like('" & query.Text & "%') order by datereceived", myconnection)

        data = New DataSet
        adapter.Fill(data, "JobOrders")
        dgjobs.DataSource = data.Tables("JobOrders").DefaultView

    Else
        grid()
    End If
```

There are still fields I included from the command, for now I only put CLIENT there from the code. Sorry if my database is like, from a stone age.

The problem is, I want to enter a text, for example "clinic", Since I have 20,000+ records, I know there are still entries from the column client like "Remita clinic", or "Delos Santos Dental Clinic" and I want that entry to show too!

Is there a way?? My brain's about to burst!

Comment: Your query needs wildcards on either end. `... like('%" & query.Text & "%') ...`. Otherwise it'll only return things starting with `clinic`. Then you need to look at doing a case insensitive like query. The best approach will depend on the database you are using

Comment: You're a god! you're my savior!